# Smaller Screen when Build and Run to Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, size

I am very new to unity and I'm making my first game, Snake. However, when I build and run it for android everything is very small and is hard to press. Scaling everything up works however when I press play everything is huge and some are out of the screen. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to your UI canvas and to the canvas scaler, set it to "scale to screen size" and change the resolution to your prefered resolution.

[canvas scaler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf69v.png)